# How to fix Docker dependencies installation?

Tags: python, macos, numpy, docker, pip

I have a movie recommender system and I am trying to create a docker image for it.

requirements.txt

```
pandas==0.22.0
requests==2.18.4
Django==2.0.6
Scrapy==1.5.1
numpy==1.14.0
scipy==1.0.0
pymongo==3.7.2
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
MAINTAINER SPARSH KEDIA

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

On running docker build ., it shows the following error:

```
error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o.d" failed with exit status 1


  Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ug5tncvh/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-zziwp791/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-wpkwq_6g/overlay --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ug5tncvh/numpy/

  ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-wpkwq_6g/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools Cython "numpy==1.9.3; python_version=='3.5'" "numpy==1.12.1; python_version=='3.6'" "numpy==1.13.1; python_version>='3.7'"" failed with error code 1 in None
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How to fix this error? or is there any other method to download the requirements.txt?

I use macos HighSierra 10.13.2.

I am new to docker, please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Docker. The numpy, scipy etc. packages needs `gcc` and `python-dev` packages to be installed on the system.

Try adding `apt-get install -y python-dev` as a step in your Dockerfile.

PS: There might be other system package dependencies for those libraries. Please check and install them as well.

Comment: Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python

E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate. How to fix this?

Comment: You would have to run `apt-get -y update` before running the install

Comment: OP nowhere says about base image he using. It could be image without `apt` "python:3" is based on ubuntu?

Comment: @AlexYu AFAIK, `python:3` is based on Debian. (https://github.com/docker-library/python)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem related to `numpy`, probably due to libraries `setuptools` and `wheel` build.

Add to requirements:

```
pip==19.0.2
setuptools==40.6.3
wheel==0.32.0
```

This link below was developed for use with AWS SageMaker, but maybe can help you:

[Dockerfile](https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/blob/master/AWS%20SageMaker/Jupyter-Folder/Dockerfile)